# How can use more id in js file?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have this HTML. How can foreach the id's in js file?

```
{foreach from=$title item=tit name=titles}

<input id="title_{id}" maxlength="150" type="text" name="title" value="" class="form-title"/>

{foreach
```

And my js is this.

```
var handleBootstrapMaxlength = function() {

    $('#title_{HERE_I NEED_THE_ID}').maxlength({
        limitReachedClass: "label label-danger",
        alwaysShow: true,
        placement: App.isRTL() ? 'top-right' : 'top-left'
    });
}
```

Comment: Use the class instead? `$('.form-title')`.

Comment: This is not HTML. If you're using a framework, tag your question with it.

Comment: Felix is working thenks!

Comment: Ok this is the answer

    $('[id^=title_]').maxlength({
            limitReachedClass: "label label-danger",
            alwaysShow: true,
            placement: App.isRTL() ? 'top-right' : 'top-left'
        }); Is better

Comment: And how can a class with ID Like <div class="airplane_{$id}"> and no [id^=title_]

Comment: The point is to use a fixed class name for all the dynamically generated elements. Then it makes selection easier. Or do you only want to select one specific element?